# Newly inserted row value to be returned using entity framework core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ExcecuteSqlCommand for update and insert, which will return an integer but i want the entire inserted or updated row. Using FromSql the updation and insertion are not happening, i am able to fetch only the items. 
How can i achieve this?

Comment: We need your code in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF , you'd better insert/update via DbContext  :

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/adding-data

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data

```
Book book = new Book();
book.Title = "Title1";

_context.Book.Add(book);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

var id = book.BookId;
```

EF will help you fill the enitity after operations , include the new added identity column value.